# Obout HTMLEditor control not working on hosting server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, obout

I am testing the latest Obout HTMLEditor control (from the .NET 3.5+ suite) in a simple .NET 4.0 web application at http://www.khazaronline.com/11.aspx  It works locally but on the hosting server there are problems. It loads up fine but when I click on some of the toolbar buttons e.g. Insert/Edit Image, popup not loading

It works when I run it locally. Has anyone come across this problem with Obout controls before? Any solutions? I am thinking perhaps there is a setting on the server which needs to be changed.

Many thanks,

hossein

Comment: What have you tried already to solve the issue?

Comment: No... It seems problem is not from the server. Please kindly check it on your end.